# How to keep counter value across all android activities, no sharedPref or SQLite solution?

Tags: android, sqlite, variables, static, sharedpreferences

I need to store button click value. It works as far as am I in the one specific activity. After I leave the activity and go back, the value of button clicks resets.

I am having the variable public static int. I would expect to keep its value.

Is there any solution different than using `SharedPreferences` and `SQLite`?

EDIT:
I want to allow users to click refresh button only 4 times a minute.
The only place where I set the value 0 is during declaration and after 1 minute passes.

Only place where I reset the count:

```
 findHORefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Constants.numberOfRefreshClicks++;
            if (Constants.numberOfRefreshClicks<4) {
                hangOuts.clear();
                getHangOuts();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You have exceeded maximum refresh clicks per minute, please wait.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes. Extend the Application class and keep the static variable there.

Comment: You probably reset this value in some method from life cycle of activity, such as onCreate or onResume or something like that. Make sure that you set your static field only on click action

Comment: but it is not good solution to keep some value in static field.

Comment: And what do you want to happen when the user hits the home button (when your app could be killed by the system) or they close the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a public class named Constants.
2. Create a static Variable in the class.
3. Access the variable in any activity with Class reference.

This way the value will not be lost.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work. I did the class, variable (public static) but it is being reset somewhere. But as I said, only places I reset it is on declaring and when the time passes.

Comment: I was reseting counter on create of the activity.